# Having some trouble creating a search date procedure

Tags: visual-studio

```
Private Sub btnSearchRaces_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchRaces.Click
    SearchRace(DatRaceSearch.Value)
End Sub
Private Sub SearchRace(DayOfTheRace As String)
    If DbConnect() Then
        lstRacesResults.Items.Clear()
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * " &
                "From TblRaces " &
                "Where DayOfTheRace = @SearchRace"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchRace", DatRaceSearch.Value)
            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()
            While rs.Read
                Dim DisplayValue As String = rs("RaceID") & " " & rs("TrackName") & "(" & rs("BookedTimeSlot") & ")" & rs("RaceEntryFee") & " " & rs("MaxNumberOfRacers") & " " & rs("CurrentNumberOfRacer")
                Dim RaceItem As New ListBoxData(DisplayValue, rs("RaceID"))
                lstCustomerSearchResults.Items.Add(RaceItem)
                End
            End While
            rs.Close()
            If lstRacesResults.Items.Count >= 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("There are no races on that date", "Race Dates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End If
        End With
        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically I just want it so the user can use the date picker to and when they press the search button on a listbox all available of the races that are happening on that date are displayed.
Thanks in advance.